# Using a CNN encoder with TimeDistributed LSTM layers for jigsaw puzzle solution

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I'm trying to build an encoder-decoder model that solves jigsaw puzzles of images.
basically, I have an image that is divided into t*t equal sized crops that I want to reconstruct.

I'm using tensorflow backed keras API.

My encoder is a pretrained CNN model with its last layer removed. So for a single crop its output is a feature vector with 256 features.
Now I want to build the LSTM decoder that should return the predicted positions of the t*t crops within the image.
The idea is that the decoder will predict the position of each crop with the position predictions of all the other crops in mind.

I'm not sure if I'm using the TimeDistributed and LSTM layers the way I need to...
I'm asking because the full model doesn't produce any improved performance over just using the CNN part (with its final layer), so I must be doing something wrong..

My model:

```
input_shape =  [t**2, image_size, image_size, num_channels]
model = Sequential()
# CNN model:
model.add(TimeDistributed(CNN, input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.05, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.05, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(t**2, activation='softmax'))
output_shape = [t**2, t**2] # t**2 crops, each with a one-hot encoded position
```

Is this the right way to do what I intended?

Comment: What loss function are you using? Have you increased your training iterations to account for the larger number of parameters?

Comment: I'm using a categorical cross-entropy loss function. Regarding the training iterations, i'm training with the pretrained CNN model, so every iteration is additional... I've also tried freezing the CNN layers weights and it didn't really help.